# Почему не работает выпадающее меню?

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

У меня есть горизонтальное меню, в котором при наведении на слово `categories` должно появляться выпадающее меню.

Мой код:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navigation ul li a.special {
  color: #b59f5b;
}

ul li.categories:hover>ul.categ_sub {
  display: block;
}

.categ_sub a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.categ_sub li a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">features</a></li>
    <li><a class="special" href="">posttypes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">pages</a></li>
    <li><a class="categories" href="">categories</a>
      <ul class="categ_sub">
        <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="">food</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fashion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вопрос: почему при наведении на `categories` не появляется выпадающее меню?

Почему `categories` стало по уровню выше, чем все остальные пункты меню?

И как это исправить?

Заранее большое спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navigation ul li a.special {
  color: #b59f5b;
}

ul li:hover ul.categ_sub {
  display: block;
}

.categ_sub {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddd;
}

.categ_sub li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">features</a></li>
    <li><a class="special" href="">posttypes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">pages</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="categories" href="">categories</a>
      <ul class="categ_sub">
        <li><a href="#">sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">fashion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо селектора `>`, который выбирает прямых детей у родителя, вероятно Вам был нужен `+`, который берет следующий к выбираемому элеменет:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navigation ul li a.special {
  color: #b59f5b;
}

.categ_sub {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.categ_sub li {
  display: block;
}

.categories:hover + .categ_sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">features</a></li>
    <li><a class="special" href="">posttypes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">pages</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="categories" href="">categories</a>
      <ul class="categ_sub">
        <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="">food</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fashion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Если нужно что бы "выпадающее меню" не пропадало, когда курсор перемещается на него** (как в первом варианте), то достаточно перевесить `hover` на родителя:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navigation ul li a.special {
  color: #b59f5b;
}

.categ_sub {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.categ_sub li {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper:hover > .categ_sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">features</a></li>
    <li><a class="special" href="">posttypes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">pages</a></li>
    <li class="wrapper">
      <a class="categories" href="">categories</a>
      <ul class="categ_sub">
        <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="">food</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fashion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```